# Firefox & HTTP Content-Disposition adds xlsx extension

Tags: http, firefox

I have a .NET application which returns the following via HTTP

```
Cache-Control: private
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="ExportToExcel_14.09.2015 09:37:51.csv"
Content-Length: 1515
Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet; charset=utf-8
Date: Mon, 14 Sep 2015 07:37:51 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
x-powered-by: ASP.NET
```

However, firefox renames the file to `{filename}.csv.xlsx`. How can I turn this off? It causes problems because the file is a CSV, but I want users to be able to open it with excel.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that setting the `Content-Type` to `application/vnd.ms-excel`, which corresponds to excel 2007, stops this strange behavior.